Why should headlessui hide the scroll bar of the web page when opening the dropdown menu? Even add padding-right: 17px?
It is always added automatically when opening the menu.
overflow: hidden;
padding-right: 17px;

Is there a way around this?
I don't need to do much when opening the dropdown menu, I'm using nextjs , tailwindcss and headlessui
I just discovered that the same thing happens with Dialog...
please tell me how to do it, thank you
